# Using HKSource.default() in an HKQuery predicate not working correctly in watchOS 7

Tags: apple-watch, healthkit, watchos-6, watchos-7

In watchOS 6, I was creating an `HKQuery` for the my app using:

`HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: HKSource.default())`

which when executed, was successfully returning HealthKit data only for my app.

In watchOS 7 when I include this predicate in the query, I get no results upon executing the query. Where the exact same query (with the `HKSource.default()` predicate) *does* return results in watchOS 6.

**Note:** I do get the expected results in iOS 14, so I am only seeing unexpected results in watchOS.

Is this a watchOS 7 bug? Or has the behavior changed for `HKSource` in watchOS 7? I can't find any relevant documentation or bug reporting around `HKSource` that would explain this difference.

Comment: This seems an issue with the latest release v7.1 of watchOS as well. Have you found any workaround?

Comment: Our business logic allowed us to change to `HKDevice.local()` on WatchOS. That definitely is not an equivalent query though so it won’t be a viable workaround in all cases.